# Insert value in blank space using Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

We have a column of data that someone appears to have inadvertently deleted 0 from a string of  characters. e.g. ABCDEF 1 when the data should read ABCDEF01.

The length of the data is each cell varies in length. How do i check for a space between a string and if it exists to insert the value 0?

Comment: Can't u just do `SUBSTITUTE(whatever, " ", "0")` ? If space is there it will get replaced, otherwise nothing will happen

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - Won't that simply insert the value "0" for every space as opposed to the length of the text?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - If i have an original list to compare with, is there to do it differently?

Comment: I didn't realize string of characters includes other "valid" spaces. Then how do you know which space to replace? Is it always the last? Also did only one 0 got replaced or multiple replacement possible?

Comment: If you have the original - why not simple copy it over?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - Rows may have been displaced as data is added or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the first space to appear is the space you want to replace, if this is the case then this is possible to do.

If your values are in column A, you can do this by searching for the first instance of " ", then using the replace function to put a 0 there.

As follows: =REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1),1,0)

Comment: The space can appear anywhere in the length of a string e.g `ABC 1`, `A BC1`, `A B C 1`,etc

Comment: From what I have read, there are some spaces you do not want to replace? Is there any pattern to these specific spaces you want to leave alone?

Comment: Yes. Would it be easier to match an existing list and fill in the blanks? For example i have a list that reads ABC01, A0BC1, A0B0C01. If the formula could identify the spaces e.g ABC 1 and insert the value 0, there would be a match.

Comment: I think that would be possible, but this solution would be overly complex with multiple formulas talking to each other repeating themselves, which just makes me think its a horrible solution. What is stoping you from using the SUBSTITUTE function? Are some spaces not supposed to be 0?